# Tricky trigonometrical triangle teaser

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

A classics teacher covering detention asked the question:

One angle of a triangle is ${96}^\circ$, find the other two angles $\psi, \theta$ given that:

> $2\sin4\theta = 2\sin2\psi + 2\cos2\psi +  3\sec3\theta +2\alpha +2\sec2\psi$

Please find the other two angles so you can go home.

Addendum: The teacher knows basic arithmetic and geometry, but trigonometry is Greek to him. His proudest mathematical moment occurred during an interview when asked to find the value of,

> $3\sin3\psi \cdot 3 \tan3\theta$ if $\psi={30}^\circ$ and  $\theta={15}^\circ$

answering even before the interviewer had finished speaking. He got the job. He said confidently

> 9

Hint

> $4\cosh3\psi + 3\sinh4\theta$

Comment: Flagged - this appears to be a textbook math problem, not a math puzzle.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: It's an enigmatic puzzle. Since when do classics teachers pose maths problems?

Comment: @MOehm - Irrelevant - the "puzzle" as posed explicitly says that the math problem is to be solved - it has nothing to do with who is administering the problem.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That may be what it looks like, but that doesn't make it true.

Comment: The point Oehm is making is that the tag is enigmatic. So there's more to it than the math question.

Comment: There's definitely something funny going on here: look at that $2\alpha$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Csin(4%5Ctheta)+%3D+2%5Csin(2%5Cpsi)+%2B+2%5Ccos(2%5Cpsi)+%2B++3%5Csec(3%5Ctheta)+%2B2%5Calpha+%2B2%5Csec(2%5Cpsi)+where+%5Ctheta%3D1.67552 this solves it :)

Comment: @Oray where did you get that value for Theta though?

Comment: @dcfyj ops, I meant $\alpha$ there :D

Comment: It should be noted that psi plus theta equals 84 degrees. And it's still a textbook math problem.

Comment: There is a little basic maths needed to solve this, but it's mostly a puzzle.

Comment: What's the "puzzle" about it? You're solving a trigonometric equation for theta and psi (and alpha, in the process).

Comment: There's too many variables to solve uniquely - the equation needs to be interpreted as a puzzle.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan $\alpha = 96°$ I think

Comment: Basically, sin, cos and sec can be read as sin, cause, and seek respectively.

Comment: A spoken/heard interpretation would make a nice puzzle, but this only uses the written form.

Comment: Classics, "so you can go home" and "Greek" makes me think that Odysseus is involved here somehow...

Comment: There may be som erelevance in Greek. According to Google translate ΣΙΝ and σιν (sigma-iota-nu) both translate to plus. I haven't been able to find an equivalent for cos or tan yet.

Comment: Nice idea Penguino, but no knowledge apart from elementary maths is needed. (Above I wrote this uses the written form - it's also OK if spoken as usual without any play on sound-alikes).

Comment: @Penguino I don't know Greek well enough to say for sure, but since I can't find σιν in a Greek dictionary,  I would venture to guess that Google Translate's σιν is simply a misspelling of συν (since both are pronounced the same in modern Greek)

Comment: Interestingly theta is always following another digit like 3 or 4 making it looks lika a 0

Comment: Also, given that the answer to the interview question is 9, and the question seems to be multiplication, that gives the possibilities that psi and theta =(3,3), (1,9), or (9,1). If 1 is substituted for psi, the first part could be read "three sin, three won." Maybe there's a reference to Greek mythology (being a classics professor) in which three people sin and win something. Is that on the right track?

Comment: @Tom Perhaps a **partial** rebus is also involved in this. Is it so?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay It's a play on numbers and letters - how the 'trigonometrical expression' translates to word/s.

Comment: @Tom Is Sin/Cos/etc... pronounced as Sine (like Sign) or 'Sin' (like evil sin) in this case?

Comment: @Adib Only spelling (sin/cos/tan/theta/psi/alpha) is important, not pronunciation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha! The last hint was very informative.

The classics teacher ...

> ... doesn't know much about trigonometry, but he certainly knows his Greek letters. He sees the equation as number–word pairs. The Greek letters are spelled out and all those arcane operators are just decoration.
>
>  These number–word pairs form single letters: The number defines which letter to extract from the word.

So the last hint ...

> ... spells out **hint**:
>
>    4 cos**h** 3 ps**i** + 3 si**n**h 4 the**t**a

The first hint ...

> ... means **nine**, which is in accordance with the teacher's answer:
>
>    3 si**n** 3 ps**i** · 3 ta**n** 3 th**e**ta

The answer to the original question is:

> **It** (is) **isosceles**.
>
>    2 s**i**n 4 the**t**a = 2 s**i**n 2 p**s**i + 2 c**o**s 2 p**s**i + 3 se**c** 3 th**e**ta + 2 a**l**pha + 2 s**e**c 2 p**s**i

So the both remaining angles of the triangle ...

> ... are both **42°**. And if that isn't a nice answer, I don't know.

Comment: Perhaps the angle in degrees would have rendered more consistantly as: 3 cos 2π + 3 max(3 cot 3ψ, 4γ + 2 sec 2ψ, 3 sin 3ψ + 3 tan 3ϑ.

Comment: $3\tan3\psi + 3\sec3\theta$ :)

Comment: I had this puzzle in my favorite and I'm just seeing this now : nice puzzle and answers

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess

> The L.H.S is an even number. So the R.H.S also must be an even number.
>  That gives a hint that 3 sec3θ is even.
>  Thereby giving Sec 3θ = 4/3 or Cos 3θ = 3/4 or θ = 41.4 /3 = 13.8 and ψ = 70.2

Comment: The LHS is not always even. If $\theta=7.5^\circ$, then LHS = 1 is odd.